# How to enable zip.dll in xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Hello I'am using xampp for windows.
I want to run:

```
https://github.com/johmue/mysql-workbench-schema-exporter
```

To export my schema.

I create my schema in mysql workbench and save it. Still when i run program i get error.

> may be it not MySQL Workbench document

To repair it need to enable zip module on xampp. I know I have to edit php.ini, but i can't find zip.dll in it, so i want to know how can I enable it.

Comment: what is your php version?

Answer (score 12):

### To enable zip.dll

- download php_zip.dll download it from [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.12.4/windows)
- extract php_zip.dll to `C:\xampp\php\ext`
- edit php.ini and add a new line `extension=php_zip.dll`
- restart apache

This should enable the zip module for you.

Comment: I downloaded php_zip-1.12.4-5.5-ts-vc11-x86 and done all. I get warning module zip already loaded and still get same error any advice ?

Comment: what is your php version? Is it 5.5?

Comment: Please note that the PECL extension is only useful for PHP/5.0 and PHP/5.1.

Comment: I use PHP Version 5.4.7

Comment: @user2217288 - How did you manage to get the Zip extension removed from PHP/5.4.7? The extension is builtin since PHP/5.3. To get rid of it you need to rebuild PHP from source code and set a compilation flag!

Comment: Actually I did not. The problem was script i was using was only run from CLI(example runs normally in browser) no idea why. Still solved :)

Comment: I still get 
`Warning: fopen(zip://interface.zip#php/functions/functions.php): failed to open stream: operation failed in S:\XAMPP\htdocs\first-coder\index.php on line 45
Can not read zip file! Please be sure, that we have in this folder the interface.zip file!` after all these steps

Answer (score 8):

You can simply solve this issue '**As of PHP 8.2.0, php_zip.dll DLL must be enabled in php.ini. Previously, this extension was built-in.**'

**Follow these steps**:

---

First open Xampp control panel and then in Xampp control panel click on **'config > php.ini'** change this and save.

***from:***

```
;extension=zip
;extension=gd
```

***to:***

```
extension=zip
extension=gd
```

Now your problem will be solved! You don't need to download and extract 'php_zip.dll'
If it is working for you, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @Guns is good but a bit out to date, the link he provided is old. For a recent version PHP you should rather go to https://pecl.php.net/package/zip And then click on the most recent release.

[image]

After that, steps from @Guns are exactly the same :

1. Extract `php_zip.dll` to `C:\xampp\php\ext` (If you installed XAMPP there)
2. Edit `php.ini` and add a new line `extension=php_zip.dll`
3. Restart Apache

Comment: Tthe link is broken

Comment: @FernandoTorres It works for me, now. but didn't worked few minutes ago. maybe the website is a bit unstable. retry later.